# "Joe Smith" is not the same as Joe Smith in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec

Hey, I'm using TDD with rails for the first time... interesting concepts. Definitely useful. That is, until I come to this. When I run my test I get:

```
1) User should build the full name correctly
    Failure/Error: @u1.fullname.to_s.should be("#{@attr[:firstname]} #{@attr[:lastname]}")
    expected Joe Smith, got "Joe Smith"
    # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.18/lib/rspec/monkey/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:4:in `run_tests'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
    # /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/server.rb:47:in `run'
```

where the test is:

```
it 'should build the full name correctly' do
  @u1.fullname.should be("#{@attr[:firstname]} #{@attr[:lastname]}")
end
```

and the supporting code is:

```
def fullname
  "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
end
```

So obviously this works, but what's with the quotation marks? Have I missed something head-smackingly obvious?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `@u1.firstname` and `@u1.lastname`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact that you are using `be` instead of `eql`. `be` is expecting a class in the way you've set it up ([documentation](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.3.0/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000161)). Try writing your spec as

```
@u1.fullname.should eql("#{@attr[:firstname]} #{@attr[:lastname]}")
```

[Documentation for eql](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.3.0/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000169)

Also, note the difference between `eql` and the method directly below it in the documentation, `equal`.

Comment: I normally write `@u1.fullname.should == "#{@attr[:firstname]} #{@attr[:lastname]}"` which i find more readable.